# Alternate SLF4J Binding or Config For Unit Test?

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I'd like to be able to switch the bindings for SLF4J for unit testing over to the simple version, but it seems there is no easy way to config this. Basically, my built project logs to a file and I'd like it to be console instead when unit testing.

I've used the antrun maven plugin before to do something like this with persistence.xml files, but that solution seems a bit heavy handed.

Does anyone out there have a solution to using alternate configs or bindings in unit tests?

TIA

Comment: which binding does the main project use?

Comment: I am using alternate configuration successfully. I use maven and I have a custom logback.xml inside test/resources. I am sure, you get even more flexibility if you use groovy based configuration.

Comment: I'm using log4j for the built project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A better approach is to facilitate your logging framework. Logback library for instance first searches for `logback-test.xml` and if it is not available, it looks for `logback.xml`. If you place `logback-test.xml` in `/src/test/resources`, it will be picked up for unit tests. In this file you configure console logging instead of file.

If you are still using Log4J, simply place `log4j.xml` in `/src/test/resources` - this folder is available on classpath *before* `/src/main/resources`, so Log4J will use it instead of ordinary `/src/main/resources` version, while still loading the latter version for final builds (`/src/test/resources` isn't even available then).

Comment: Hmm, maybe my m2Eclipse version is old. b\c I tried using vanilla log4j with 2 properties files and it keeps picking up the 'main' version (at least this is what is reflected in the 'target' folder.