# How to make a Logger for System.out

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, system.out

I am wondering how to get org.slf4j.Logger for System.out. I know this is not good, but I need it for testing purposes.

Thank you so much.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5903253/127971 => use slf4j + logback, and two different logback configuration files; one for test, one for main

Answer (score 21):

It is possible to use slf4j-simple and make it write to the standard output by setting a system property when the program starts:

```
System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile", "System.out");
```

More information at http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html

Comment: Link is 404....

Answer (score 14):

Put simplelogger.properties in your classpath and put this line in it:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
```

This will cause SLF4J Simple Logger to log to Standard Output instead of Standard Error.

Comment: Also, it doesn't need to be simplerlogger.properties, it worked when I put this in my application.properties file

Answer (score 6):

SLF4J is a logging facade.
You need a logging implementation.

Nowadays, Logback is the recommanded logging framework.

To log to System.out, you have to use the ConsoleAppender in Logback configuration file.

Example :

```
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <target>System.out</target>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%-40.40c [%5.5thread] %-5p %X - %m%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: I think logback (or log4j) is overkill for this purpose. slf4j-simple is intended for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [sysout-over-slf4j](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/)

Comment: This answers the wrong question.  The OP asked how to write slf4j messages to System.out.  sysout-over-slf4j sends messages written to System.out to the slf4j framework.  These are 2 different things.  Correct answer is by Jean-Philippe Briend