# Override SLF4J implementation in unit tests for Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, maven, intellij-idea

How to override SLF4J implementation for unit tests?

For Android application im using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-android</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

But unfortunately, running any unit test gives me:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

Due to stubbed Android JAR's in Maven Central.

I have a lot of utility and tiny service classes which don't use Android API. But some of them use slf4j logger's which causes this error.

How can i test them without splitting classes into two separate artifacts?

The way which i currently use is to remove `slf4j-android` and add `slf4j-simple` in `test` scope.

I found that i can configure Maven surefire plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <classpathDependencyExcludes>
        <dependencyExclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-android</dependencyExclude>
    </classpathDependencyExcludes>
</configuration>
```

But IDE... No... Looks like IntelliJ IDEA silently ignores this setting and run tests with slf4j-android.

Similar question:
[Alternate SLF4J Binding or Config For Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903088/alternate-slf4j-binding-or-config-for-unit-test)

But not suitable for slf4j-android.

Maybe somebody knows more convenient and working solution for this problem?
Maybe use another logging framework. But i don't know any other which works well with Android.

BTW: Robolectric didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not perfect solution - workaround

In my project I have separated application logic (`my-app-library`) and unit tests (`my-app-test`) into two different modules. With this configuration I can test logic from my-app-library with standard logger.

Configuration from `my-app-test`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.android.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-android</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. But i've found that SLF4J takes `first` binding on classpath. So i can simply put `slf4j-simple` in `test` scope above `slf4j-android`. Yes in this case i will get a warning from slf4j every time i run tests. But logging will still work. What i don't want is to split module. Because it's just for tests. Currently i don't plan to reuse that code, just want to test them.